# Filter data by react

Tags: reactjs

I have got series of data that contains some objects in one array(json file) and it will be shown by react.

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
data: [],
   .
   .
   .
currentPage: 1,
itemsPerPage: 20,
value: '',
filterTerm: null,
startIndex : 0,
endIndex : 4,
}}}

[{'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc25', 'hotelinfo': {'hotelsearch': {'realname': 'Korston Hotel Moscow'}},{'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc24', 'hotelinfo': {'hotelsearch': {'realname': 'Lavanta Hotel'}},{'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc28', 'hotelinfo': {'hotelsearch': {'realname': 'Stanpoli Hotel'}}]
```

There is a paging which displays 4 pages by default and show the rest of pages by clicking next button.

```
render() {
 const { data, currentPage, itemsPerPage,startIndex,endIndex } = this.state;
 const indexOfLastItem = currentPage * itemsPerPage;
 const indexOfFirstItem = indexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage;
 const currentItems = data.slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem);
 const renderHotel = currentItems.sort((a, b) => a.total - b.total).filter(this.filterData).map((item, i) => {
   return  <div class="item">
             <span>{item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname}</span>
         </div>
 });
  const pageNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(data.length / itemsPerPage); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
    }

const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.slice(startIndex, endIndex).map(number => {
return (
   <li className={(this.state.currentPage === number ? 'active ' : '') + 'controls'}
   key={number}
   id={number}>
   {number}
 </li>
)});
return (
 <div>
 <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleInputChange} class="hotelName" /><span onClick={this.handleSearch} class="searchbtn">search</span>
   {renderHotel}
  <ul id="page-numbers" class="pagenumDef">
  <li onClick={this.decremant} class="nexprev"><span class="fa-backward"></span></li>
   {renderPageNumbers}
   <li onClick={this.increment} class="nexprev"><span class="fa-forward"></span></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
)};
```

I have an input(class="hotelName") which user start to type in (e.g user type 'Korston' ) and click a button and new result should just contain the data of hotels those contain 'Korston' name.

```
handleInputChange(event) {
this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
}
handleSearch= () => {
 let inputval = this.state.value
 const {value} = this.state;
 this.setState({filterTerm: value});
}
filterData = (item) => {
  const { filterTerm: term } = this.state;
  if (term === null) {
  return true;
  }
 let inputval = this.state.value
 inputval = term.toLowerCase()
.split(' ')
.map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
.join(' ');
 let realname = item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname
 let len = realname.length
 if (len !== 0) {
  if (realname.includes(inputval)) {
   return true
 } else {
  return false
  }
 }
 return false;
}
```

The main problem is that function **handleSearch** filters the data in a page which we are in . For example when we are in page 3, filter will be done in  series of data that are in page 3 not the whole data in all pages.I want filtering will be done in whole of data(e.g 400 nembers of data) not (20 numbers of data in for example page 3).Makes sense?

Comment: If you are filtering only the current page, it means that you filter the paginated result. You should first filter your list then paginate the filtered list

Comment: Thanks @Niels Dominguez .I tried this approach you mentioned, but When the user start tying 'Korston' the result shows the information of 'Korston Hotel Moscow' , then the user types 'Lavanta'. I expect the result shows the information of 'Lavanta Hotel' but seems when ever user types a text(e.g Korston) for the next time the filtering will be done in previous result not the default result.Sorry for may explanation.Does it make sense

Comment: Ah sorry, you mean that you get the result of the previous state and not from the actual one?

Comment: Yes  @Niels Dominguez . Exactly

Comment: Np :) please upvotes my answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead this:

```
const pageNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(data.length / itemsPerPage); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
    }
```

you can try to directly generate an array (faster and maybe avoid immutability pb), here you would create the pageNumbers in the state:

```
   const renderPageNumbers =  new Array(data.length / itemsPerPage).slice(startIndex, endIndex).map((number, index) => {
        this.setState({ pageNumbers: [...this.state.pageNumbers, index+1]})
    ...rest of your code
```

Comment: Hi @Niels Dominguez. Thanks for your answer.You mean my code should be something like this?

Comment: const renderPageNumbers =  new Array(data.length / itemsPerPage).slice(startIndex, endIndex).map((number, index) => {
 this.setState({ pageNumbers: [...this.state.pageNumbers, index+1]})
    return (
     <li className={(this.state.currentPage === number ? 'active ' : '') + 'controls'}
       key={number}
       id={number}
       onClick={this.handleClick}>
       {number}
     </li>
   )});

Comment: Replace number by index+1:

  const renderPageNumbers = new Array(data.length / itemsPerPage).slice(startIndex, endIndex).map((number, index) => { this.setState({ pageNumbers: [...this.state.pageNumbers, index+1]}) return ( <li className={(this.state.currentPage === index+1 ? 'active ' : '') + 'controls'} key={index+1} id={index+1} onClick={this.handleClick}> {index+1} </li> )});

Explanation:

It is not important that pageNumbers array is filled with 1,2,3 or with empty, because after you map it. The 2nd argument of map is the index, so it will increment +1 each time.

Answer (score 0):

You tried this one?

Your code:

```
const currentItems = data.slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem);
const renderHotel = currentItems.sort((a, b) => a.total - b.total).filter(this.filterData).map((item, i)
```

What you could do:

Delete currentItems

```
const renderHotel = data.sort((a, b) => a.total - b.total).filter(this.filterData).map((item, i).slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem);
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't work.Can you explain what would be the different when I delete currentItems?

Comment: At beginning i thought you wanted to filter all the data and after do the pagination.
In your code you slice and after you filter the sliced result. In my example you filter all the list, then you slice the filtered result.

You can check my new answer, maybe the pb is the for loop... not sure, but the calculation will be faster as you spare one loop.